# What is the simplest way to solve this primitive function?

Tags: functions

I have some trouble with the rules to calculate the primitive function where $y = a^n$. For example:
$$\int(4x^3(x^4+5)^5)dx$$
I want to break out the constant 4 to get: $4\int^\ (x^3(x^4+5)^5)dx$, then I want to set $(x^4+5)^5$ to $(z)^5$ so I can see that the primitive is $\frac{1}{6}*(z)^6$.
But now I do not get any futher, do I have to take the primitive of the value of $z$ now so I get: $$\int(\frac{1}{6}*(z)^6*P(z))$$
And the value of $x^3$ I have ignored uptill now, is it just to take the primitive of that value and multiply it to the function? If so than I would get: $$4[\frac{x^4}{4} * \frac{1}{6} * (z)^6*P(z)]$$ 
Where $P(z)$ stands for the primitive of the value of $z$. Can some one please tell me where I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int  4x^{ 3 }(x^{ 4 }+5)^{ 5 }dx=\int { (x^{ 4 }+5)^{ 5 } } d\left( x^{ 4 }+5 \right) =\frac { { \left( x^{ 4 }+5 \right)  }^{ 6 } }{ 6 } +C$$

Comment: Sorry but where did $4x^3$ go?

Comment: this term entered under derivative $4x^{ 3 }\Longleftrightarrow d\left( x^{ 4 }+5 \right) $

Answer (score 3):

Let $x^4+5=z$, then you got $dz=4x^3dx$, so $$
\int 4x^3(x^4+5)^5dx=\int z^5dz=\frac{z^6}{6}+K=\frac{(x^4+5)^6}{6}+K
$$